# Find the value of $\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} 2^{\sin x} \text dx +\int_\frac{5}{2}^4 \sin^{-1}(\log_2(x-2)) \text dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Find the value of $$\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}2^{\sin x} \text dx +\int_\frac{5}{2}^4 \sin^{-1}(\log_2(x-2)) \text dx.$$

I tried to solve it using the concept: $$\int_{a}^b f(x)\text dx=\int_{a}^b f(a+b-x)\text dx.$$ 
My step is as follow:

$$I=\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}2^{\sin x}dx=\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}2^{-\sin x}dx.$$

$$I=\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)dx=\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}f(-x)dx$$

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use that concept? Then people will be able to hopefully spot if you have gone wrong anywhere, and will be able to give you a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this problem is designed to use the formula

$$\int_a^bf(x)\;dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\;dx = bf(b)-af(a)$$

([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions))

You only need to rewrite the second integral using $x\mapsto x-2$ as

$$\int_\frac{5}{2}^4 \sin^{-1}(\log_2(x-2)) \;dx= \int_{\frac 12}^{2}\sin^{-1}(\log_2(x))\;dx$$

So, you get

$$\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}2^{\sin x} \text dx +\int_\frac{5}{2}^4 \sin^{-1}(\log_2(x-2)) \text dx$$
 $$=\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}2^{\sin x} \text dx +  \int_{\frac 12}^{2}\sin^{-1}(\log_2(x))\;dx= \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot 2+ \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac 12 = \frac 54\pi$$